# Linux CPU frequency scaling affects timerfd accuracy

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, cpu, frequency

On a Linux driven single core embedded Cortex-A8 based machine I'm encountering problems with `timerfd`: I need to trigger some IO every couple of milliseconds and up to now everything went fine with a timer I created this way:

```
int _timer_fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_NONBLOCK);
int _flags = 0;
itimerspec _new_timer;
_new_timer.it_interval.tv_sec = interval / 1000000;
_new_timer.it_interval.tv_nsec = (interval % 1000000) * 1000;
_new_timer.it_value.tv_sec = _new_timer.it_interval.tv_sec;
_new_timer.it_value.tv_nsec = _new_timer.it_interval.tv_nsec;
timerfd_settime(_timer_fd, _flags, &_new_timer, NULL);
```

.. and `select()`ing on the file descriptor.

The CPU is running at 800MHz by default and it can be scaled down to 300MHz. Even at the lowest frequency the timer is triggering regularly even with high system load and heavy IO.

Now here is the problem: when I set the CPU frequency governor to `ondemand` the timer misses wake-ups for **several seconds** (I've seen up to 2800ms) when switching frequency.

The IO I'm talking about involves uploading large files (network IO, extracting/CPU, writing to flash). Just creating/extracting a large archive alone seems to be not a problem.

I modified [this handy little Python script](https://github.com/tsavola/pytimerfd) which uses `timerfd` to print the CPU frequency and time diff every 100ms and I can reproduce the problem! Running `test.py` and started the upload (heavy IO) gives me the following output:

```
f=300000 t=0.100021, count=01 *
f=600000 t=0.099609, count=01 *                    <== switch, but no problem
f=600000 t=0.099989, count=01 *
f=300000 t=0.100388, count=01 *                    <== switch, but no problem
f=300000 t=0.099874, count=01 *
f=300000 t=0.099944, count=01 *
f=300000 t=0.100000, count=01 *
f=600000 t=0.099615, count=01 *                    <== switch, but no problem
f=600000 t=0.100033, count=01 *
f=600000 t=0.099958, count=01 *
f=600000 t=0.100003, count=01 *                    <== IO starts
f=600000 t=0.100062, count=01 *
f=600000 t=0.100318, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.418505, count=04 ****                 <== 3 misses
f=800000 t=0.081735, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.100019, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099284, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.100584, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.100089, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099623, count=01 *
f=720000 t=1.854099, count=18 ******************   <== 17 misses
f=720000 t=0.046591, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.099038, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.100744, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.099240, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.100029, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.099985, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.100007, count=01 *
f=800000 t=2.715434, count=27 ***************************  <== 26 misses
f=800000 t=0.085148, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099992, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099648, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.100367, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099406, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099984, count=01 *
f=720000 t=2.446585, count=24 ************************  <== 23 misses
f=720000 t=0.054219, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.099947, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.099284, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.100721, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.099975, count=01 *
f=720000 t=0.100089, count=01 *
f=800000 t=2.391552, count=23 ***********************  <== 22 misses
f=800000 t=0.015058, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.092592, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.100651, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099982, count=01 *
f=800000 t=0.099967, count=01 *
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3126086/1668622) answer which suggests to set the priority of my process but with no effect.

Here are my current conclusions:

- the problem is not caused by my C-Program because I can reproduce it with a little Python script
- the CPU performance is not the problem because fixing the frequency to 300MHz works well
- the process which produces the heavy load have to meet certain requirements (see below) - just doing network IO or CPU intense operations will not work
- the timer gaps seem to occur only when the `gpg` process gets fed with certain data

**So my question is**: I need an accurate timer with an interval of about about 10ms (a couple of ms jitter is ok). Can I achieve this with `timerfd`? What are my alternatives?

The used Kernel version is 4.4.19 (OpenEmbedded/Yocto)

**Reproducing**

Currently I know no other way to reproduce the described behavior than the following:

- on the embedded device with network access have `nginx` installed `proxy_pass`ing port `80` to some other port, e.g. 8081
- run `receive.py` on the device which will listen to `POST` requests, recieve a large file and pipe it to `GnuPG`
- run `test.py` on the device to observe CPU frequency and timer accuracy
- set cpu governor to `ondemand`: `echo ondemand > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`
- use `upload.py` on another machine to send a 10M file with random content to the embedded
- the content of the uploaded data seems to be important!  `upload.py <ip/hostname> 10000000` will generate a random byte stream and store it to a file named `data-out` before `POST`ing it - in most cases you will see no timer gaps - in case you can observe them you can keep the file and reuse it later
- running `upload.py` from the embedded device (no networking) or leaving out `nginx` will not work!

**Files**

> This is the modified version of `test.py` which produces the output above
>
> ```
> import asyncore, time, timerfd.async
>
> class TestDispatcher(timerfd.async.dispatcher):
>     def __init__(self, *args):
>         super().__init__(*args)
>         self._last_t = time.time()
>
>     def handle_expire(self, count):
>         t = time.time()
>         f  = open('/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq').readline().strip('\n')
>         print("f=%s t=%.6f, count=%0.2d %s" % (f, t -  self._last_t, count, '*' * count))
>         self._last_t = t
>
> dispatcher = TestDispatcher(timerfd.CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
> dispatcher.settime(0, timerfd.itimerspec(0.1, 1))
> asyncore.loop()
> ```
>
> `receive.py`
>
> ```
> import subprocess, http.server, socketserver
> class InstallationHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
>     def do_POST(self):
>         gpg_process = subprocess.Popen(
>             ['gpg', '--homedir', '/home/root/.gnupg', '-u', 'Name', '-d'],
>             stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>         tar_process = subprocess.Popen(
>             ['tar', '-C', '.', '-xzf', '-'],
>             stdin=gpg_process.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>         content_length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
>         while content_length > 0:
>             content_length -= gpg_process.stdin.write(
>                 self.rfile.read(min(1000, content_length)))
>         gpg_process.stdin.close()
>         self.send_response(201)
>         self.end_headers()
>
> socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
> socketserver.TCPServer(('', 8081), InstallationHandler).serve_forever()
> ```
>
> `upload.py` - provide either a file name to upload or a number of bytes to 
>   generate
>
> ```
> import http.client, sys, os
> if os.path.exists(sys.argv[2]):
>     print('read.. %r' % sys.argv[2])
>     b = open(sys.argv[2], 'rb').read()
> else:
>     print('generate random data..')
>     b = os.urandom(int(sys.argv[2]))
>     open('data-out', 'wb').write(b)
> b = bytes(b)
> print('size=%d' % len(b))
> h = http.client.HTTPConnection(sys.argv[1])
> h.request('POST', '/upload/calibration_data', b)
> print(h.getresponse().read())
> ```

Comment: Can you post your platform and the modified script ?

Comment: @Ezequel: I've posted the script - which details of the system do you need? It's a Phytec phyCORE AM3359 with a OpenEmbedded Linux kernel 4.4.19

Comment: I just wanted to know the SoC. Each SoC has different cpufreq and timer implementation.

Comment: So, it's not the cpufreq transitions alone because under no load there is no jitter. And, it's not the load alone because you can set the governor to `performance` (which fixes the frequency). Is that right?

Comment: Thats right - I can even set it to `powersave` or set a fixed frequency and the timer works as expected. And it's hard to find a task which shows the bad behavior: currently I have to upload random data via `nginx` and let `GnuPG` try to decrypt it. Uploading data or decrypting data alone has no effect on the timer.

Comment: And I would not call this effect "jitter" - there are massive gaps! Under normal circumstances the timer is jittering with about 0.001ms (look at the data) - the effect I'm observing looks like the whole system is freezing for about 2-3 seconds (about a million times more than the jitter)

Comment: ....indeed. I just tested your test.py script on a Beagle bone black, with various kinds of loads and could not reproduce it. Can you add a script to create the load that reproduces this?

Comment: I've added details on how I get this behavior - I haven't tried it on a totally different device yet but I will try it on a Tinkerforge RED brick tomorrow..

Comment: i'll give that a try here and inspect the box. fwiw, it smells like a bug somewhere. i'll edit my answer with a detailed analysis of what can be happening later.

Comment: Quick question: where is your rootfs running from? NAND UBIFS? MMC? RAM?

Answer (score 4):

*Preliminary answer*. Let's assume you don't want to disable cpufreq or do any other invasive kernel configuration change that would result in changes in the power consumption.

Let me assume that the jitter is not coming from some weird interaction between the cpu clock and the timer clock, which would be quite hard to eliminate.

Let's assume also that you are willing to hack your way a little bit. In that case... use your own hardware timer!

ARM SoCs typically have many hardware timers, and Linux often consumes just two of them: one to feed the timers (i.e. `timerfd` and other timer interfaces), and one for timekeeping. That means that you usually have a lot of hardware timers that are idle and available.

Unfortunately, Linux does not offer any framework or interface to use them, so you have to do your own thing. For instance [here](https://github.com/unwireddevices/timer-irq-handler) there is an example for MIPS SoC AR9331.

Doing it for your ARM SoC will be simply a matter of reading the datasheet, checking the registers and perhaps adapting that example, or coming up with your own solution.

The jitter will be much less, because it will be a hardware timer, producing interrupts and therefore not affected by regular load.

If you want to have even less jitter, you could try fast interrupts (FIQ). Bootlin (former Free Electrons) has explained this awesome trick, on their [blog](https://bootlin.com/blog/fiq-handlers-in-the-arm-linux-kernel/).